# How to fetch the refresh token In all API's using FastAPI Oauth

Tags: fastapi, access-token, refresh-token, request-headers

Using the External API access token and refresh token will be fetched.
By creating a new API that accepts client id and client secret as input and gives a response  access token and refresh token.
example:{
"message": "Validation successful",
"data": {
"AccessToken": "accesstoken",
"ExpiresIn": 3600,
"TokenType": "Bearer",
"RefreshToken": "refreshtoken"
}
}
I need to fetch both access token and refresh token to use in all other APIs to work which needed to pass in header of all API's.
I am able to get only access token but I need both refresh token as well as access token how can I achieve this using FastAPI.

Looking forward for the help.
Thank you in advance

Comment: How are you handling the response from the authentication API now? If you're accessing `AccessToken` - couldn't you just access `RefreshToken` instead?

Comment: I need both an access token as well as refresh token.
I am using HTTPBearer token for authentication

Comment: Yes, but you're asking how to fetch the token - you apparently already have the response that contains the AccessToken under one key and the refresh token under another key - why can you access `AccessToken` in that response, but not `RefreshToken`?

Comment: I am accessing token In all APIs using token = HTTPBearer() and 
header_token : str = Depends(token) so only I am able to fetch access token

Comment: How are you sending the refresh token to your service? i.e. the client has to actually send the token for you to be able to read it.